# Procedural tile edges blending

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my 2d game I'm generating map from tiles. Because I don't want to have hard transitions between textures like in Minecraft for example, I have to generate textures procedurally.

I've got variable:

```
Dictionary<long, Sprite> textures;
```

Also I've got function:

```
Sprite GenerateSprite(byte[] _gridSums, int[] _ids) {...}
```

This function creates texture and for each gridSum and id adds next layer to it.

GridSum shows where is neighbour with specific texture.

If gridSums[n] in binary equals 10000000 and ids[n] for example equals 1, it means that there is neighbour with texture of id 1 at south west direction.

I also have got function:

```
long GetSprireID(byte[] _gridSums, int[] _ids) {...}
```

It is used to get texture from textures dictionary. If dictionary doesn't contain it, then it is generated by GenerateSprite and added to the dictionary for future reusing.

This function is problem for me. Multiple gridSums and ids combinations can generate same texture. Because of that I can't just simply use shortcut function.